# Need to make a library of mammalian coding sequences

Tags: pcr, protein-expression

I want to clone ~100 different coding sequences from human or mouse into an expression vector to analyze phenotypes in tissue culture. I can do all of the steps, but I'm not sure what I should use as the template for my reactions. Ideally, I would purchase a pool of full length cDNAs from a bunch of organs, and amplify from that. Less ideally, I can generate cDNAs myself, from multiple organs and pool them. Does anyone have suggestions on a template source?

Comment: If you plan to take one isoform for each one of the genes, then I see no point in amplifying them pools of tissues.

Comment: The goal is to do a miniscreen for proteins of annotated with a specific function (there are about 100 genes). The idea is to automate the task as much as possible, without spending too much time choosing isoforms or fusion points.  I just don't have experience doing this, so I'm not sure if such libraries exist, or if I essentially need to start from scratch from cDNAs and gene specific primers. I figures that by pooling cDNAs I would most likely amplify the most abundant isoform.

Answer (score 1):

- Verify where these transcripts are generally present (this should not be difficult for common organisms)
- If they are all expressed in a certain tissue use cDNA from that tissue
- If not then pool the cDNAs from different tissues such that all genes can be amplified
- cDNA libraries (including whole organism) are also available and you may obtain them from the nearest repository (I guess NCBI also provides).

Some other things you can do:

- Ask the primer synthesis company to provide primer sets it in a
  96well format.
- DNA synthesis is also a decent option (it takes something like $0.5 
  per base pair), but that can be expensive if your cDNAs are huge.